# Using Fetch method to extract properties to HTML

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

I'm learning Javascript and I still have some trouble to understand the way to use Fetch Api method.

I'm stuck at the very first step of my project which have to make us more comfortable with the Fetch method. I am suppose to build the first page from e-shopping using this method.

////  HTML

```
  <div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center ">

  <main class="row justify-content-around w-100 flex-wrap">

      <article id="article-card-1" class="col w-30">

          <img src="" class="product-img" id="img-art-1">
      </article>

      <article id="article-card-2" class="col w-30">

          <img class="product-img" id="img-art-2" src="">

      </article>
      <article id="article-card-3" class="col w-30">

          <img class="product-img" id="img-art-3" src="">

      </article>

      <article id="article-card-4" class="col w-30">

          <img class="product-img" id="img-art-4" src="">
      </article>

      <article id="article-card-5" class="col w-30">

          <img class="product-img" id="img-art-5" src="">

      </article>

  </main >
```

//// Javascript

```
  const img = document.getElementById("img-art-1");

  const getImgUrl = fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/cameras');

  getImgUrl
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => console.log(data[0].imageUrl))
      .then(replaceImageSrc => img.src = replaceImageSrc[0].imageUrl)
      .catch(error => console.log("Erreur" + error))
```

From this I'm able to get the first promise, the second allow me to acceed where the imageUrl is contained in the JSON file but I can't use it in my HTML.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sGvEqHkDyFc (FR) --> This video shows exactly what I'am suppose to do but still does nothing on my project and I'm starting getting pretty lost.

EDIT: Here is my JSON

```
    Array(5) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} ]
​
0: Object { _id: "5be1ed3f1c9d44000030b061", name: "Zurss 50S", price: 49900, … }
​​
_id: "5be1ed3f1c9d44000030b061"
​​
description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
​​
imageUrl: "http://localhost:3000/images/vcam_1.jpg"
​​
lenses: Array [ "35mm 1.4", "50mm 1.6" ]
​​
name: "Zurss 50S"
​​
price: 49900
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
1: Object { _id: "5be1ef211c9d44000030b062", name: "Hirsch 400DTS", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.", … }
​​
_id: "5be1ef211c9d44000030b062"
​​
description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
​​
imageUrl: "http://localhost:3000/images/vcam_2.jpg"
​​
lenses: Array(3) [ "50mm 1.8", "60mm 2.8", "24-60mm 2.8/4.5" ]
​​
name: "Hirsch 400DTS"
​​
price: 309900
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
2: Object { _id: "5be9bc241c9d440000a730e7", name: "Franck JS 105", price: 209900, … }
​​
_id: "5be9bc241c9d440000a730e7"
​​
description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
​​
imageUrl: "http://localhost:3000/images/vcam_3.jpg"
​​
lenses: Array [ "25mm 4.5" ]
​​
name: "Franck JS 105"
​​
price: 209900
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
3: Object { _id: "5be9c4471c9d440000a730e8", name: "Kuros TTS", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.", … }
​​
_id: "5be9c4471c9d440000a730e8"
​​
description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
​​
imageUrl: "http://localhost:3000/images/vcam_4.jpg"
​​
lenses: Array [ "50mm 1.7", "35mm 1.4" ]
​​
name: "Kuros TTS"
​​
price: 159900
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
4: Object { _id: "5be9c4c71c9d440000a730e9", name: "Katatone", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.", … }
​​
_id: "5be9c4c71c9d440000a730e9"
​​
description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
​​
imageUrl: "http://localhost:3000/images/vcam_5.jpg"
​​
lenses: Array(3) [ "50mm 1.4", "35mm 1.8", "28-200mm 2.8/4.5" ]
​​
name: "Katatone"
​​
price: 59900
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
length: 5
​
<prototype>: Array []
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue. I had to set the path. Then I solved my problem as @tuomokar suggested.

The final code looks like this:

```
 const getJsonData = fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/cameras').then(response => response.json());



getImgUrl = getJsonData
   .then(data => document.getElementById("img-art-1").src = data[0].imageUrl)
   .catch(error => console.log("Erreur" + error))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `then` functions are a function that promises have. The fetch returns a promise and so does `response.json()`. Because of that you chain the `then` calls for them.

But `console.log(data[0].imageUrl)` doesn't return a promise so you can't use `then` for the result anymore.

Replacing `.then(data => console.log(data[0].imageUrl))` with `.then(data => img.src = data[0].imageUrl)` should fix your problem.

For more information on promises you can read up on [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) for example.

Comment: const img = document.getElementById("img-art-1");

Even if I focus on him with .getElementById? 
Will I have to create it with createElement then retry?